# when does a generalized integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I know that when $f(0)=0$,the integral
$$I=\int_0^\varepsilon \frac{1}{f(x)}dx $$
may not diverge (like $f=\sqrt{x}$.

So I want to know if a function $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$ such that $f(0)=f’(0)=0$, can we say that for any $\varepsilon$, the integral $I$ must diverge.

I don’t know how to prove it ,or give a counterexample.

Comment: What's the relationship between $f(x)$ and $I$?

Comment: @5xum sorry! I have rewritten the equation.

Comment: @Andrei Sorry! I have rewritten the equation.

Comment: Can you assume that $f'$ is continuous on some interval $(0,t)$ or do you specifically want to avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditions are sufficient to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$$

---

**Method 1**:

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then, by the definition of differentiability, there exists some function $o$ such that, for small values of $h$, you have

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\cdot h + o(h)$$

and the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{o(h)}{h}=0.$$

In your case, $x_0=0$ gives you

$$f(x)=0+0\cdot x + o(x)=o(x)$$

so you basically know that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$$

---

**Method 2**:

By another definition of $f'$, you have

$$0=f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-0}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

---

In both cases, once you have the limit, it is trivial to show that for values of $x$ close to $0$, you have $|f(x)|<|x|$, or, for positive values of $x$, simply $|f(x)|<x$.